# How can I sort a dimensional array output by key value from jekyll data yaml files?

Tags: liquid, jekyll-theme

I need the name from several `yml` files sorted, alphabetically on the output.

I've tried to add `| sort: 'name'` in my for loop. I get:

```
 Liquid Exception: no implicit conversion of String into Integer in pages/index.html
```

### Sample `_data/cat/example1.yml`

```
name: "test1"

permalink: "/test"

twitter: "WIP"

facebook: "WIP"

web: "WIP"
```

I have at least 3 yml files in my test in the `/cat` folder.

### Sample Include File

```
<div class="row">
{% for cat_hash in site.data.cat %}
{% assign cat = cat_hash[1] | sort: 'name' %}
<div class="col-6 col-12-narrower">
    <section>
      <header>
        <a class="image featured" href="{{ cat.permalink }}" title="{{ cat.name }}"><h3>{{ cat.name }}</h3></a>
      </header>
        <p>{{ cat.web }}</p>
     </section>
</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

I've read several examples with this sort issue. Just not sure if any of the hash results in the loop answered my situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your not applying the sort on a valid array of hashes.

If you do a `{{ site.data.cat | inspect }}` you get something like `{"t1"=>{"name"=>"test1"}, "t2"=>{"name"=>"allo"}, "t3"=>{"name"=>"jekyll"}}` (I've simplified data files for brevity but it works the same with more complicated data files like yours).

You currently are applying sort filter on `{"name"=>"test1"}` object which cannot sort itself.

What you need to do is to get all your data hashes in a single array. then you can sort it.

```
{% assign datas = "" | split: "" %}
{% for cat in site.data.cat %}
  {% assign datas = datas | push: cat[1] %}
{% endfor %}

DEBUG : {{ datas | inspect }}
```

You now have an array that can be sorted.

```
{% assign datas = datas | sort: "name" %}
DEBUG : {{ datas | inspect }}
```

You can now print your datas sorted by name.

Full code :

```
{% assign datas = "" | split: "" %}
{% for cat in site.data.cat %}
  {% assign datas = datas | push: cat[1] %}
{% endfor %}

{% assign datas = datas | sort: "name" %}

<div class="row">
{% for cat in datas %}
  <div class="col-6 col-12-narrower">
    <section>
      <header>
        <a class="image featured" href="{{ cat.permalink }}" title="{{ cat.name }}">
          <h3>{{ cat.name }}</h3>
        </a>
      </header>
      <p>{{ cat.web }}</p>
    </section>
  </div>
{% endfor %} 
</div>
```

Note that `inspect` filter is used for debugging only.

Comment: I tried

<div class="row">
{% assign datas = "" | split: "" %}
{% for cat in site.data.cat %}
  {% assign datas = datas | push: cat[1] %}
  {% assign datas = datas | sort: "name" %}
{{ datas | inspect }}
<div class="col-6 col-12-narrower">
    <section>
      <header>
        <a class="image featured" href="{{ datas.permalink }}" title="{{ datas.name }}"><h3>{{ datas.name }}</h3></a>
      </header>
        <p>{{ cat.web }}</p>
     </section>
</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: So the full answer is {% assign datas = "" | split: "" %}
{% for cat in site.data.cat %}
  {% assign datas = datas | push: cat[1] %}
{% endfor %}
{% assign datas = datas | sort: "name" %}
<div class="row">
{% for cat in datas %}
<div class="col-6 col-12-narrower">
    <section>
      <header>
        <a class="image featured" href="{{ cat.permalink }}" title="{{ cat.name }}"><h3>{{ cat.name }}</h3></a>
      </header>
        <p>{{ cat.web }}</p>
     </section>
</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>